# Erro Undefined offset em Script de Cotação

Tags: php

Tenho esse script *PHP* que uso para pegar cotações de moedas do *infomoney*, porém está dando os seguintes erros.

> Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp64\www\cotacao.php on line 15 
>   Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp64\www\cotacao.php on line 17 
>   Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp64\www\cotacao.php on line 24 
>   Undefined offset: 8 in C:\wamp64\www\cotacao.php on line 29 
>   Undefined offset: 11 in C:\wamp64\www\cotacao.php on line 34 
>   Undefined offset: 12 in C:\wamp64\www\cotacao.php on line 39 
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\wamp64\www\cotacao.php on line 44

**Esse é o codigo em PHP.**

```
    <?php
if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/cambio" , "r" )) 
{
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de cotação" ;
    exit;
}
$conteudo = '';

while(!feof($fp)) 
{ 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
}
fclose($fp);
$valorCompraHTML = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo); 

$valorCompra = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5]));

$valorVendaHTML = explode(' ', strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[6]));

//Estes são os valores HTML para exibir no site.    
$valorVendaHTML = explode(' ', $valorVendaHTML[0]);
$valorVenda  = trim($valorVendaHTML[0]) ;

//Compra Turismo.
$valorCompraT = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[7]));
$valorCompraT = explode(' ', $valorCompraT);
$valorCT  = trim($valorCompraT [0]) ;

//Venda Turismo.
$valorVendaT = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[8]));
$valorVendaT = explode(' ', $valorVendaT);
$valorVT  = trim($valorVendaT[0]) ;

//Compra Euro.
$valorCompraE = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[11]));
$valorCompraE = explode(' ', $valorCompraE);
$valorCE  = trim($valorCompraE[0]) ;

//Venda Euro.
$valorVendaE = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[12]));
$valorVendaE = explode(' ', $valorVendaE);
$valorVE  = trim($valorVendaE[0]) ;+

//Estes são os valores numéricos para cálculos.   
$valorCompraCalculavel = str_replace(',','.', $valorCompra);
$valorVendaCalculavel  = str_replace(',','.', $valorVenda);
?>
```

**Linhas onde ocorre o erro:**

> **15** - $valorCompra = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[5])); 
>   **17** - $valorVendaHTML = explode(' ', strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[6])); 
>   **24** - $valorCompraT = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[7])); 
>   **29** - $valorVendaT = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[8])); 
>   **34** - $valorCompraE = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[11])); 
>   **39** - $valorVendaE = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[12])); 
>   **44** - $valorCompraCalculavel = str_replace(',','.', $valorCompra);

Comment: O que da pra dizer é que esses indices não existem pode usar `isset()` para verificar.

Comment: Quais são as linhas 15, 17, 24, 29, 34, 39 e 44?

Comment: Coloquei as linhas no post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitivamente o `explode` não é uma das melhores formas de capturar elementos *HTML* de um código. Outro ponto é que, no site, não existem elementos com a classe *numbers*.

Ao invés do `explode`, você pode utilizar [regex](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) (apesar de não ser a melhor opção); [DOMDocument](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) e [DOMXPath](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php); Pode inclusive utilizar bibliotecas com esse proposito, como a [querypath](https://github.com/technosophos/querypath).

Vamos começar com funções nativas do *PHP*.

---

### Capturando HTML do site.

Para captura de informações de sites, nós podemos utilizar o [file_get_contents](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) para capturamos o *HTML* do site.

Com essa função nós precisamos passar apenas a *URL*, mas você também pode passar o argumento `flag`:

- *FILE_TEXT*: Ler o *HTML* no padrão *UTF-8*
- *FILE_BINARY*: Ler o *HTML* no binário.

E também o argumento `context`. Nele nós podemos passar um objeto do tipo [Stream Context](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stream-context-create.php). Assim poderemos passar alguns valores como `Cookies`, `User-Agent` etc.

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/cambio");
```

---

### Carregando os dados recebidos

Para tratar esses dados, precisamos utilizar a classe [DOMDocument](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php). Com ele nós podemos carregar o *HTML*, capturar através de uma *tag* ou *ID*; Podemos criar e ler atributos etc.

Para isso basta instanciar o objeto e utilizar o método `loadHTML`.

```
$dom = new domDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
```

> O **@** serve para ignorar os erros do HTML, como por exemplo, o não fechamento de uma *tag*.

Com isso já é possível listar os elementos que contém os dados de nome, preço e venda das moedas. Caso seja uma estrutura *HTML* básica, bastaríamos:

1. Utilizar o método `getElementsByTagName`
2. Percorrer todos os elementos necessários através de um `foreach`
3. Filtra-los e exibir na tela.

Mas queremos algo mais simples (já que a estrutura do site não é tão simples para nosso código), por isso iremos utilizar a classe [DOMXPath](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php).

---

### Filtrando os elementos necessários

Para filtrar os dados iremos utilizar a classe [DOMXPath](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php), com ela nós conseguiremos criar *queries* para tornar as buscas pelos elementos, mais simples.

Essa classe, infelizmente, não funciona com o *jQuery*. Ela trabalha com expressões [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/). Através dessas expressões, nós conseguiremos buscar os elementos. Ela funciona da seguinte forma:

> - **nodename**: Seleciona todos os elementos com o nome `nodename`
> - **/**: Selecione o elemento root
> - **//**: Seleciona o elemento no documento a partir do nó atual que corresponde à seleção, independentemente de onde eles estão
> - **.** *(ponto)*: Seleciona o elemento atual
> - **..** *(dois ponto)*: Seleciona o elemento "pai"
> - **@**: Seleciona a partir dos atributos

<sup>Para saber mais, segue o link da [documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)</sup>

Agora podemos avançar e começar a selecionar os elementos, mas primeiro vamos instanciar o objeto [DOMXPath](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php) e depois utilizaremos o método `query`.

```
$tables = $xpath->query("//table[@class=\"table-general\"]");
$values = $xpath->query(".//tbody/tr", $tables->item(0));
```

Dessa forma iremos acessar todos os elementos `table` que possui a classe `table-general`, logo depois acessaremos todos os elementos `tbody tr` da primeira tabela encontrada.

Agora só precisamos executar um `foreach` na variável `$values` para obtermos os elementos `td` (onde estão os valores).

---

### Filtrando os valores necessários

No `foreach` supracitado, iremos utilizar mais uma vez o método `query`. Isso nos retornará um objeto do tipo [DOMNodeList](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnodelist.php).

Esse objeto retornado nos possibilita ter acesso ao método `item`, que por sua vez retorna um [DOMNode](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnode.php). Com esse [DOMNode](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnode.php), nós podemos retornar o conteúdo do elemento ou um atributo dele.

```
$currencies = [];

foreach($values as $value) {    
    $currency = $xpath->query(".//td", $value);

    /* Acessa o conteúdo em texto do primeiro elemento TD */
    $name          = trim($currency->item(0)->textContent);

    /**
     * Acessa o conteúdo o segundo elemento da tag TD,
     * após isso capturamos o "irmão" (próximo elemento na mesma raiz), no caso o IMG
     * e então captura o atributo SRC
     */
    $img           = trim( $currency->item(1)->firstChild->nextSibling->getAttribute("src") );

    /* Acessa o conteúdo em texto do terceiro elemento TD */
    $purchasePrice = trim($currency->item(2)->textContent);

    /* Acessa o conteúdo em texto do quarto elemento TD */
    $salePrice     = trim($currency->item(3)->textContent);

    /* Armazenamos em um array para posteriormente exibir aos usuários. */
    $currencies[] = [
        "img"           => $img,
        "name"          => $name,
        "purchasePrice" => $purchasePrice,
        "salePrice"     => $salePrice,
    ];
}
```

---

### Exibindo os dados para o usuário

Essa passo é opcional, iremos apenas demonstrar (para quem tiver dúvida), como exibir esses valores na tela.

Irei utilizar o [Pure-CSS](https://purecss.io/) para esse passo, porém ele também é opcional.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="pure-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Moeda</th>
            <th>Compra</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <!-- Percorre todo o array criado -->
        <?php foreach($currencies as $currency): ?>
        <tr>

            <!-- Concate o endereço do site com o caminho da imagem -->
            <td><img src="<?php echo "http://www.infomoney.com.br{$currency['img']}" ?>" /></td>

            <!-- Exibe nome da moeda -->
            <td><?php echo $currency['name'] ?></td>

            <!-- Exibe valor da compra -->
            <td><?php echo $currency['purchasePrice'] ?></td>

            <!-- Exibe valor da venda -->
            <td><?php echo $currency['salePrice'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Código Completo**](https://gist.github.com/valdeir2000/511c2ab8f414ae033dad25e92bf464eb)

---

### Utilizando a biblioteca `QueryPath`

Serei breve aqui, apenas postarei o código comentado. Para explicações mais detalhes basta acessar a [documentação](https://github.com/technosophos/querypath).

```
<?php

/* Carrega as bibliotecas via composer */
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

/* Acessa e baixa o HTML do site */
$qp = html5qp("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/cambio");

/* Captura os atributos "tr" da tag "tbody" da primeira tabela coma  classe "table-general" */
$values = $qp->find("table.table-general:first tbody tr");

/* Percorre os valores capturados */
foreach($values as $value) {
    /* Armazenamos em um array para posteriormente exibir aos usuários. */
    $currencies[] = [
        "img"           => trim($value->find('td:eq(2) img')->attr("src")),
        "name"          => trim($value->find('td:eq(1)')->text()),
        "purchasePrice" => trim($value->find('td:eq(3)')->text()),
        "salePrice"     => trim($value->find('td:eq(0)')->text()),
    ];   
}
```

[**Código Completo**](https://gist.github.com/valdeir2000/511c2ab8f414ae033dad25e92bf464eb)

Comment: Valdeir, tenho uma planilha excel com CEP e NUM, preciso adicionar esses valores no site e consultar um por um e retorno dessa consulta exibir em uma tabela para usuário, como poderia fazer isso com esse método seu, poderia dar uma luz?