# Conexão com site externo para busca de dados

Tags: php

Um site que uso, tem como base WWW-authentication para fazer Login.

Seria possível montar no meu site um script PHP para acessar essa página, fazer login com os dados que eu determinar numa string, e entrar no site exibindo apenas algumas partes do conteúdo?

Exemplo: Se tiver uma caixa de busca lá, ao clicar em "Conectar-se" no meu site, quando for feita a conexão, aparecer a caixa e partir daí, eu digitar os dados e aparecer o resultado da consulta do site?

Comment: Isso parece [Web Scraping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping). Talvez isso possa lhe ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/278576/99718 ou ainda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277387/99718

Comment: Isso é amplo demais para responder, pois **depende do site especifico** que esta tentando acessar, se ele tiver anti-CSRF ou usar Recaptcha você não vai conseguir. Não existe uma maneira unica global especifica de resolver isto.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal. :D