# XPath para coletar dados

Tags: xpath

Estou desenvolvendo um bot para realizar a captura de determinadas informações de sites, porém quando vou tentar coletar as informações relacionadas a descrição do item coletado, o mesmo não percorre o `while` efetivando as demais coletas.

Ele salva as informações diferentes, porém adiciona a mesma descrição para todos os itens.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
var target = trs[tr_num].SelectNodes("//button[@class='btn btn-default']")
    [0].Attributes["data-target"].Value.CopyAfter("#").Trim();

string xpathCompara = ("//section[@id='about']/div[@id='" + target + "']");
```

Comment: Talvez ajude-o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277387/99718

Comment: Olá Valdeir, este exemplo se aplica para C# também?