# Pegar informações de outra pagina com PHP

Tags: php, html

Tem alguma forma de pegar informações de outra pagina, como `<title>`, `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>`, `<meta name="description" content="DESCRIÇÃO DE OUTRO SITE"/>`, ate mesmo imagem da pagina como isso: `<meta property="og:image" content="/81.jpg" />`

Isso vindo e um parâmetro de uma URL

```
$url = $_GET ["url"];
```

Ou seja quando eu ter uma URL COM `link.php?url=https://siteapegar.com` eu consiga pegar todas essas informações acima.

tem alguma forma de fazer isso ?

Comment: Faz tempo que não mexo com php, mas tentou com file_get_contents("http://exemplo.com.br/", false, $context)?

Comment: pesquise no site por file_get_contents e cURL, essa é uma pergunta já tratada extensivamente aqui (estou sem tempo de achar as originais, mas se alguém puder fazer, ajuda)

Comment: Resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277387/99718